# R-Studio error "> " signs became "+"

Tags: machine-learning, r, dataset

We have a homework on R-studio and while applying steps I've got an error, as shown below:

```
+ +library(simpleaffy)
+ +>hist(dat)
+ +plotAffyRNAdeg(RNAdeg, col=cols)
+ +end()
+ +options(error = expression(NULL))
+ +>hist(prostate)
+ +>hist(prostate)
+ +source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
```

These are just some random codes which I wrote while trying to dispose pluses
They must be `>` to run the steps, but I can't run because of this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit both `>` and `+` at the beginning of the lines. Your code has to look like this:

```
library(simpleaffy)
hist(dat)
plotAffyRNAdeg(RNAdeg, col=cols)
end()
options(error = expression(NULL))
hist(prostate)
hist(prostate)
source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
```

Comment: We realized that it occurs because of a function in R. We applied almost all steps and there is a legend() function, after applied it, we encountered this error. Normally, when we put ")" , there shouldnt be any problem but it still gives +.

Comment: @Aybuke Maybe you forgot the final `"` for a string.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to ask programming questions on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

A line starting with `+` means R is expecting more input. It usually occurs because you haven't closed a parenthesis.

Comment: What should i do then? Should i restart and write all the codes again or? I really dont know how to solve this problem..

Comment: If you're typing the > symbols, that's likely the cause of your issues. Don't type those.